# installation of usb network adapter without internet connection

Tags: drivers, usb, internet

I have a desktop with ubuntu 16.04 without an internet connection. In order to get internet access I bought a TP-Link AC600 Nano WiFi adapter.

I have a (work)laptop which I can use to download drivers.

I can find some information on installing a driver, however DKMS is needed.

How to install a driver for this device?

hope someone is willing to point me in the right direction.

thanks in advance,

Sebastiaan

Answer (score 0):

Connect your phone using a USB cable and install whatever you need.

Comment: that was real easy, thnx!